# How to include technical report number in bibtex and also retain the institution name with it?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style

My MWEB:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

In the references.bib file I include,

```
@techreport{abc2017xyz,
title={def},
author={Lmn, O},
year={2017},
institution={pqr}}
```

I want the reference to include the word "Technical Report" and with the report number, say, 127. Also, the name of the institution should be included with it. How to proceed?

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)? Which style do you use?

Comment: Written in MWEB format..

Comment: @samcarter Any suggestions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the number with `number={127},`, all your other wishes seem to be already there.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@techreport{abc2017xyz,
title={Title of the report},
author={Lmn, O},
year={2017},
number={127}, 
institution={Name of Institute}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

[image]